Can i make this circuit smaller?
I have an external device and I need to detect voltage high/low on two wires.  The high=12v, low=0v.  I am using an Arduino Zero (3.3v).  I am thinking of using A1 and A2 connected as follows...

link in tinkercad
In which the yellow boxes at the bottom are the A1,A2 and ignore the pushbuttons.
This design uses 4 resistors (2x10k, 2x2.2k) minimal.  Normally both inputs are HIGH.  Each one will go to LOW momentarily.  It is sufficient for me to detect if either one goes LOW. In other words, is there a way for me to map the AND of both inputs to a single analog pin on the Arduino?  Ideally using less resistors? (i.e. I want to avoid more soldering.)

the link is dead

the input is LOW, and goes HIGH when the button is pressed

what functionality are you trying to have? ... please update your post with an explanation

put the two switches in series

You may try this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This should work as a wired and, provided the diode thresholds are lower than the Arduino's input low threshold.

Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it, but it doesn't work. It seems the 12v high is much stronger than the low.  If both are low, then the digital input is low. However if either input is high, then digital input is hign.  So it is actually an OR instead of AND.  perhaps my diodes where the wrong kind.

@JohnHenckel if either input is high, then digital input is hign ... that is not the expected behavior of that circuit ... you may have miswired something
